# Very slow installations

Tags: performance, hosting, loading-time

I've got a client with five installs on one server - all different sites and EE versions. Everything has been fine up to now, but every site has suddenly become very slow including the control panel. I've checked everything I can think of, but is there anyway to definitely tell if hosting is the problem rather than EE?

Comment: first of all, i'd check the queries in the output profiler. You'll likely see some queries that take more than 1 second. In my case the queries that were slow are things like update stats, update session kind of queries. Turned out that there where some settings changed in the hosting and they needed to set "innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=2" for things to speed up again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you had some before/after stats from something like template profiler then your host will likely say it's EE.

Given nothing has changed (sites haven't all been updated or become insanely popular over night) I'd wager your host has either altered something at their end or, if on shared hosting, other sites are consuming more of the available processes.

You need to have a chat with your host. Grab some stats from all sites via template profiler - dB requests, memory et al so you have some base numbers to discuss.